# check try exception IndexError in python

Tags: python, exception

I have this two pieces of code:

```
try:
    error1=tree.xpath[...]
    error2=tree.xpath[...]
except IndexError:
    print 'hello'                  #piece 1


try:
    error3=tree.xpath[...]
    error4=tree.xpath[...]
except IndexError:
    print 'hello'                  #piece 2
```

Depends on what `xpath pattern` is, one of two pieces work well. For example for some sites piece 1 is working fine (so I have to comment piece 2) and for some other sites piece two is working fine (so I have to comment out piece 1).

How can I mix and use both pieces in all conditions for all web sites I am using them?

Comment: What's the problem you have with your code?

Comment: Can you post an example of code? Blocks of code are the same except by variable names.

Comment: Is there the case where piece 1 and piece 2 work fine? If so, do you have to comment both or none?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest exceptions:

```
try:
    error1=tree.xpath[...]
    error2=tree.xpath[...]
    print "Method 1 succeed"
except IndexError:
    print "Method 1 failed, trying method 2"
    try:
        error3=tree.xpath[...]
        error4=tree.xpath[...]
        print "Method 2 succeed"
    except IndexError:
        print 'Both method failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code by introducing a new variable which keeps a check if the commands were successful.

```
success = False
try:
    error1=tree.xpath[...]
    error2=tree.xpath[...]
    success = True
except IndexError:
    print 'hello'                  #snippet 1

if not success:
    try:
        error1=tree.xpath[...]
        error2=tree.xpath[...]
    except IndexError:
        print 'hello'                  #snippet 2
```

Comment: I think you're confusing Python with another language on your `if` statement line. `if not success` is valid Python,  `if !success` is the syntax of other languages ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Joel Edited my answer. It's been 3 years to this answer :)

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't even realize! I was searching by "relevance" instead of "newest".